# Imagem não e exibida ao ser listada no Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Não estou conseguindo listar as imagens salvas no e node com o express, quando tento listar a minha View não exibe a imagem.

***Meu arquivo de configuração:***

```
module.exports = function(){

    //recuperando a biblioteca do express
    var express = require("express");
    //retornando a função da biblioteca do express
    var app = express();
    //setando o ejs com engine view
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    //setando uma caminho para as views
    app.set('views', './app/views');

    var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

    //responsavel load automatico dos modulos
    var consign = require('consign');

    //responsavel por capturar os dados do formulario
    var BodyParser = require('body-parser');

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + './app/public'));

    //permite codificação pela url (urlformdata)
    app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    app.use(fileUpload());

    //lendo as rotas e o banco, colocando dentro de app (servidor)
    consign({cwd: 'app'}).include('infra/dbConnection.js').then('models').then('rotas').then('controllers').into(app);


    return app;

}
```

***Minha View***

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
            <tr>
                <% for(var i=0; i<lista.length; i++) {%>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="<%= lista[i].id %>"><%= lista[i].nome %></a>
                        <img src="./public/images/<%= lista[i].imagem %>"  height="42" width="42">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <% } %>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

***Minha Rotar***

```
module.exports = function(app){

    app.get('/usuario', function(request, response){
        app.controllers.usuarioController.index(app, request, response);
    });

    app.get('/usuario/adicionar', function(request, response){
        app.controllers.usuarioController.adicionar(app, request, response);
    });

    app.post('/usuario/salvar', function(request, response){
        app.controllers.usuarioController.salvar(app, request, response)
    });

    app.get('/usuario/:id', function(request, response){
        app.controllers.usuarioController.detalhe(app, request, response);
    });

}
```

**Meu Controller***

```
module.exports.index = function(app, request, response){    

    //instanciando o retorno da funcao da conexao
    var connection = app.infra.dbConnection();
    //instanciando a model e passando a conexao com parametro
    var usuario = new app.models.Usuario(connection);

    usuario.Listar(function(erro, retorno){
        response.render('usuario/index', { lista: retorno });
    });
    console.log(app.path);
}

module.exports.adicionar = function(app, request, response){
    response.render('usuario/formulario_cadastro');
}

module.exports.salvar = function(app, request, response){

    //instanciando o retorno da funcao da conexao
    var connection = app.infra.dbConnection();
    //instanciando a model e passando a conexao com parametro
    var usuario = new app.models.Usuario(connection);

    var dataForm = request.body;
    var name = request.files.imagem;

    dataForm['imagem'] = name.name;

    console.log(name);
    name.mv('./public/images/' + dataForm.imagem ,function(err){});
    console.log(dataForm);
    usuario.salvar(dataForm);
    response.redirect('/usuario');
}

module.exports.detalhe = function(app, request, response){

    //instanciando o retorno da funcao da conexao
    var connection = app.infra.dbConnection();
    //instanciando a model e passando a conexao com parametro
    var usuario = new app.models.Usuario(connection);

    var id = request.params.id;

    usuario.Detalhe(id, function(erro, retorno){
        response.render('usuario/detalhe', { usuario: retorno });
    });
}
```

**Minha estrutura de pastas**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O array `lista` vem de onde?

Comment: Poste o código do arquivo `usuarioController.js` que é a real controller, o que você postou foi o arquivo de rotas do usúario.

Comment: @LucasHenrique pronto coloquei o controller que estava faltando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

voce nao precisa colocar o ./public/images/  ja que a pasta public ja esta definido.

tente `<img src="images/<%= lista[i].imagem %>"  height="42" width="42">`

Answer (score 1):

Quando você define algo como `static` (que no caso foi a pasta *public*), ele fica como publico na raiz do seu servidor, então você não precisa definir o caminho completo, e sim a partir da pasta *public*.

No caso (como ja foi respondido pelo nosso colega @jcardoso):

```
<img src="images/<%= lista[i].imagem %>">
```